# reading file from mongodb return same file every call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to read a file from my db and for some reason it returns the same file every time without considering the name of the file which is the way im trying to get it.

BACK:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    mongoose
        .connect('mongodb://dbname.mlab.com:12345/db', {
            auth: 
                {
                    user: 'user',
                    password: 'pw'
                }
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('connection successful')
            var gridfs = require('mongoose-gridfs')({
                collection:'fs',
                model:'files',
                mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
            });

            Attachment = gridfs.model;


            // large file example
            var stream = Attachment.readByFileName(req.body.imageName);
            console.log(stream)

            stream.on('data', (image) => {
                base64data += image.toString('base64'); // converting buffer to base64 string
                base64data = base64data.replace('undefined', '');
                console.log(base64data)
            });
            stream.on('close', () => {
                res.send(base64data)
            });

        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
})
```

FRONT:

```
getImageBuffer = (imageName) => {
  this.forceUpdate();
  console.log('this is the image im fatching', imageName)
  axios
    .post('https://myserver.com/readCarImg', {
      imageName: imageName
  })
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({
      imageBuffer:`data:image/jpg;base64,${res.data}`
    })
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('there was problem getting image buffer', e)
  })
}
```

REMOVING IMAGE FROM STATE:

```
  showModalMarker = () => {
      this.setState({
        imageBuffer: undefined
      })
  }
```

NOTE : I am logging `imageName` to be sure that Im getting different name each time, and I am. And also I am removing the Image string from the state before every new call to make sure it clean. And i am logging the response from the server and can confirm its the same buffer returning every time. I am using `gridfs` to store the images in my mongo db if it make some difference

Comment: Why are you sending images as streams of base64 characters? You should have a route like `.get('/file/:name', (req,res) => ...` in which you simply return the file content from GridFS as if it was a "real file" by just using `.pipe()` on the binary output stream. Unless you thought you needed to Base64 encode when you wrote it, which you did not need to do. You're basically misinterpreting the principle of why inline base64 gets used. For your purposes, use a piped result that "looks like" a file and simply set the "filename" ( API endpoint ) in an img tag src attribute

Comment: @NeilLunn hay man THANK YOU for the tip! I changed my route to use your suggestion and it works like a charm! I still dont really know why it isnt worked before but now it reload 10 times quicker and it show every file I ask! so Thanks!